# Online videos on Measure theory.

Tags: measure-theory, education, online-resources

I am looking for lecture videos on Measure Theory. I am not able to find any. 
Looking forward for your response.

Comment: http://courses.bilkent.edu.tr/videolib/course_videos.php?courseid=12

Comment: The link Michael provided is dead now. Here is a replacement:
http://courses.bilkent.edu.tr/course_videos.php?courseid=12

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You might want to take a look at [this](http://www.youtube.com/view_play_list?p=17567A1A3F5DB5E4). And [here](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-125-measure-and-integration-fall-2003/) are some lecture notes (no video) you might find useful.

Comment: Great resources! I recommend adding a textual description so that people can still google in case the links break

Comment: If I traced the first link accurately, it points to this source now: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL17567A1A3F5DB5E4 which is a series of YouTube videos named "Probability Primer" by "mathematicalmonk".

Answer (score 8):

This link is useful also. One complete video course is there.

http://nptel.ac.in/courses/111101005/

Comment: These are lectures by Prof. Inder Rana, who is the author of the book ["An Introduction to Measure and Integration"](http://http://www.ams.org/bookstore-getitem/item=GSM-45)  Second Edition, Published by American Mathematical Society. (Graduate Studies in Mathematics Series.)

Answer (score 6):

I'm not sure how much of the subject you know already, but [mathematicalmonk's youtube channel](http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL17567A1A3F5DB5E4&feature=plcp)
has some nice videos introducing the subject and moving into a proper treatment of probability.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe this link is also of interest in relation to the question http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLD4489A54EA4C7C1D

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to comment on the currently accepted answer but unfortunately, I do not have enough reputation to do that. For some reason, the link in that answer does not work for me. With some tricks I find this link to be working

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Tk4ubu7BlSk&list=PL17567A1A3F5DB5E4

which is "Probability Primer" by "mathematicalmonk". This channel is also pointed out by another answer.

I hope this helps!